# My don't starve world disappeared

Tags: dont-starve, dont-starve-shipwrecked

I was playing *Don't Starve: Shipwrecked* and I was on day 30, then my game crashed and when I reopened it my world (slot) just disappeared.
Is there any way to get my world back?